# Order of $5+2^k\mathbf{Z}$ in $(\mathbf{Z}/2^k\mathbf{Z})^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

When I test for small values of k, it seems that the order of $5+2^k\mathbf{Z}$ in $(\mathbf{Z}/2^k\mathbf{Z})^*$ is $2^{k-2}$. How do I prove this?

Comment: I think you mean $5+2^{k}\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $5+\mathbb{Z}/2^{k}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Induction. $5 = 1+2^2$, then $5^2 = 1 + 2\cdot 2^2 + (2^2)^2 = 1 + 2^3\cdot(1+2)$. Then $5^{2^2} = (1 + 2^3\cdot(1+2x))^2 = 1 + 2^{3+1}(1+2x) + 2^{2\cdot 3}(1+2x)^2 = 1 + 2^4(1+2y)$. Et cetera.

Comment: drhab//That's what I meant, thanks. I corrected. Daniel Fischer// Thanks. That's awesome.